# Selecting only time from date

Tags: sql, oracle

If I do:

```
SELECT PRESERV_STARTED
FROM HARVESTED_L;
```

I will get values like:

```
23-12-1999 00:00:00
21-03-2000 22:01:37
...
```

And so on. (`PRESERV_STARTED` has type `DATE`)

What I want is only to select the date with time part, where the time is not `00:00:00`, so that I can omit those.
There is a lot of info about a solution to this, saying I can do something like:

```
select cast(AttDate as time) [time]
from yourtable
```

And for older versions of sql server:

```
select convert(char(5), AttDate, 108) [time]
from yourtable
```

And yet other proposals are:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108)
```

I tried all of these, among a few others, but no luck.
So my question is, having a date like: `23-12-1999 00:00:00`, how do I select the time part?

What comes most intuitive to me (mixing with the proposals I found) is something like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(PRESERV_STARTED), 108) AS timePortion
FROM HARVESTED_L;
```

I get an error from this code, saying `"Missing expression"`. In fact, this is the error I get from most of the proposals I tried.

I am using Oracle SQL Developer `version 4.1.1.19`

Comment: You are using SqlServer expressions on Oracle?

Comment: SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS' FROM DUAL, change sysdate to your field and DUAL with your table name.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Do you want to select all rows but modify the column? Or do you want to select a subset of the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to select only the rows for which the time part of the date column is not 00:00:00. You don't have to get the time part in order to do this. You can use [TRUNC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions220.htm#SQLRF06151) function which (by default) returns date with the time part truncated. Here's an example:

```
SQL> select * from t;

        ID D
---------- -------------------
         1 2016-01-01 00:00:00
         2 2016-01-01 00:01:00
         3 2016-01-01 00:01:23

3 rows selected.

SQL> select * from t where d <> trunc(d);

        ID D
---------- -------------------
         2 2016-01-01 00:01:00
         3 2016-01-01 00:01:23

2 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle you can just format the date(time) however you like:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(preserv_started, 'HH24:MI:SS')
FROM   harvested_l
```